# .NET Activex control access violation in MFC application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mfc, activex

Background: I developed an Activex control in .NET, but found it was causing stability issues in various applications that used it.  I managed to find a series of steps, from sample applications, similar unstabilities outlined below.

I have a sample Activex control that I've downloaded from the Dev-Center website called 'CSActivex' (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSActiveX-b86194f8)

It was fairly easy to build, I just loaded the project up in VS2010 Express (C#) and it compiled into a .dll

I then created a sample MFC application from VS2008 C++ to model a legacy applications (it does not use any .NET).  The target is the simple dialog based GUI that has an About box.

I registered the csactivex.dll with regasm and just copied the dll to the VS IDE folder, so I can insert the Activex control at design time, and then to the Debug folder, so it can be found during runtime.

At design time, I insert the CSActivex control onto the About dialog box, it appears with no surprises.  After building and copying the dll to the Debug folder and run a debug session, if I continually navigate to the about box, click in various places on the control, close the about dialog and repeat a few times, I start to see messages in the output log about access violations, and it starts to look like this:

```
'CSActivexMFC.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Windows.Forms\63406259e94d5c0ff5b79401dfe113ce\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll'
'CSActivexMFC.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll'
'CSActivexMFC.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.2600.5581_x-ww_dfbc4fc4\GdiPlus.dll'
'CSActivexMFC.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Accessibility\11eb4f6606ba01e5128805759121ea6c\Accessibility.ni.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x79f4c2f7 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000b.
First-chance exception at 0x79f4c2f7 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000b.
```

While it does not crash in the debugger, I can't help but think this in not good, and I have a feeling that it may be related to the instability of other .NET Activex controls.  If I can figure out a way to solve this issue, the same resolution may help the original control.

I tried breaking on the exception, but it appears to happen in a few different places. one stack trace when I closed the applications is below:

> mscorwks.dll!79f4c2f7()         [Frames below may be incorrect and/or
>   missing, no symbols loaded for mscorwks.dll]
>     mscorwks.dll!79f4c370()         mscorwks.dll!79faaa91()
>     mscorwks.dll!79faa858()         mscorwks.dll!79faa9ad()
>     mscorwks.dll!79faa9d9()         mscorwks.dll!7a079480()
>     mscorwks.dll!7a0798e8()         mscorwks.dll!7a043f25()
>     ole32.dll!77525834()        rpcrt4.dll!77e799f4()
>     rpcrt4.dll!77ef421a()       ntdll.dll!7c915239()
>     ntdll.dll!7c91542b()        ntdll.dll!7c91534a()
>     ntdll.dll!7c915239()        ntdll.dll!7c91542b()
>     ntdll.dll!7c91534a()        ntdll.dll!7c915f75()
>     ntdll.dll!7c9155ed()        ntdll.dll!7c915ce9()
>     ntdll.dll!7c96f07c()        ole32.dll!77600c15()
>     ole32.dll!77600bbf()        ole32.dll!7752ad31()
>     ole32.dll!7752ac56()        ole32.dll!7752b771()
>     ole32.dll!77600e1f()        ole32.dll!7752b7ab()
>     ole32.dll!7752b5e1()        ole32.dll!7752b54e()
>     user32.dll!7e418734()       ole32.dll!7752b54e()
>     ole32.dll!7752b54e()        ole32.dll!7752b54e()
>     ole32.dll!7752b54e()        ole32.dll!7752f2d0()
>     ole32.dll!7752f23e()        ole32.dll!77557237()
>     mscorwks.dll!79f9e14d()         mscorwks.dll!79f9e0b4()
>     mscorwks.dll!79f9e018()         mscorwks.dll!79f4c879()
>     mscorwks.dll!79f3bb76()         mscoreei.dll!603cc966()
>     mscoreei.dll!603d1f25()         mscoree.dll!790186ad()
>
> > msvcr90d.dll!_*crtCorExitProcess(int status=2)  Line 716    C   msvcr90d.dll!*_crtExitProcess(int status=2)  Line 722 + 0x9 bytes   C 
> >       msvcr90d.dll!doexit(int code=2, int quick=0, int retcaller=0)  Line
> >     644 + 0x9 bytes   C   msvcr90d.dll!exit(int code=2)  Line 412 + 0xd
> >     bytes C   CSActivexMFC.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 595  C 
> >       CSActivexMFC.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup()  Line 399 C 
> >       kernel32.dll!7c817077()

I was hoping someone may have run into this before, I'm running into this on mulitple machines (home and at work) and at least have it narrowed down to either a problem with CSActivex not doing something it should, or something in MFC.

so my question is how to get these samples working without the access violations?

Edit:

Just opening the about window and closing it repeatedly eventually results in a crash in the debugger (unhandled exception) with a stack trace below, to me it looks like an object that was destructed is being destroyed again?

```
First-chance exception at 0x00400003 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00400003 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x003a005c in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
First-chance exception at 0x00460020 in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00460020.
First-chance exception at 0x78b6ba1d (mfc90ud.dll) in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000018.
Unhandled exception at 0x78b6ba1d (mfc90ud.dll) in CSActivexMFC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000018.


    mfc90ud.dll!CDataSourceControl::~CDataSourceControl()  Line 2431 + 0x2d bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!CDataSourceControl::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x11 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!COleControlSite::~COleControlSite()  Line 77 + 0x22 bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!COleControlSite::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x11 bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!COleControlSiteOrWnd::~COleControlSiteOrWnd()  Line 161 + 0x24 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!COleControlSiteOrWnd::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x11 bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!COleControlContainer::~COleControlContainer()  Line 199 + 0x1c bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!COleControlContainer::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x11 bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnDestroy()  Line 786 + 0x24 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=2, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0, long * pResult=0x0012f510)  Line 2042  C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=2, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x0012f88c, HWND__ * hWnd=0x002c04fc, unsigned int nMsg=2, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x002c04fc, unsigned int nMsg=2, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 403   C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd=0x002c04fc, unsigned int nMsg=2, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 441 + 0x15 bytes  C++
user32.dll!7e418734()   
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]    
user32.dll!7e418816()   
mfc90ud.dll!CThreadSlotData::GetThreadValue(int nSlot=6623744)  Line 268    C++
user32.dll!7e428eec()   
ntdll.dll!7c90e473()    
user32.dll!7e42b1a8()   
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::DestroyWindow()  Line 1007 + 0xd bytes    C++
90909090()
```

Comment: You should be able to invoke *old* stuff *from* .Net (using Interop) ... but you certainly shouldn't be writing any *new* stuff in ActiveX, if you can avoid it.  That goes double for MFC!  IMHO...

Comment: One of the limitations is to support older applications that only know about Activex and not .NET..i.e. like VB6

Comment: http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [MSDN Blog by David Kline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) on What is a First Chance Exception.

From Blog

> Does a first chance exception mean there is a problem in my code?
>
> First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a problem in the code. For applications / components which handle exceptions gracefully, first chance exception messages let the developer know that an exceptional situation was encountered and was handled.
>
> For code without exception handling, the debugger will receive a second chance exception notification and will stop with a unhandled exception.

And by looking at another [MSDN Blog by David Kline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/18/440150.aspx) it will tell you how to Stop on a First Chance Exception to see what caused it.

And this [MSDN Forum Posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/da1eedcd-50d3-46b0-bfd8-f3c840d72b55)

Comment: reading addresses that low means null pointers are being dereferenced, that is not good.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 I did not say there was not a problem, but just that normaly it isn't, because it is raised before it is handled by user code. Plus I gave a few links on how to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The following code will generate the same First Chance exceptions of the access violation kind before actually crashing after many iterations  

int x[1];
int i = 0;
while(true)
{
 x[i++] = 0;
}
So, I have a feeling what I'm seeing in the debugger is not benign